# View - Single Page Application

Tags: angularjs, single-page-application

Quando descobri o estilo SPA fiquei  bem animado, mas fui pesquisar sobre alguns frameworks que fazem isso, vi que são mvc's, porem totalmente voltados para o cliente(front) e isso nao agradou muito, pois o meu foco é de me aprofundar no lado do servidor.

Eu entendi que o back serviria somente para servir dados e persistência(básico) como uma Rest e as demais no cliente.

Quero saber se tem como utilizar um desses frameworks somente a parte da "view"(single pages application)? Para poder criar interfaces Spa e ainda poder manter parte da responsabilidade no back, meio a meio.

Não tenho conhecimento  sobre esses frameworks como angularjs e etc, alguem mais experiente poderia me orientar.

Grato.

Comment: A questão é que a vantagem que é mais vendida do SPA é a tirar o processamento do lado servidor e colocar no cliente! A sigle page só é alcançada porque esse processamento é sempre no cliente, se você submeter algo pro servidor será renderizada uma nova página com base na resposta do servidor, entende? Não tem como deixar só a view porque a view em si caracteriza a diminuição de processamento do lado do servidor.

Comment: E se fosse no caso do Vue.JS que o foco é ser a view do MVC? O que eu quero é poder incluir interfaces SPA nas minhas aplicações de forma que não mudasse drasticamente o desenvolvimento. Deixando parecido como era, só que com duas tecnologias, vue na view cuidando da interface(spa) e o "alguma tecnologia back-end" cuidando do modelo e controler, fornecendo os dados e as regras de negócios. Mantendo meu foco que é o back-end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por definição qualquer *framework SPA* lida apenas com o aspecto `V` da solução (por serem *frontend-based*). Alguns implementam internamente MVC/MVVM/MV* para coordenar processos internos - por exemplo o AngularJS é MVC, no sentido em que HTML representa View, Controllers são exatamente isso e Services/Factories (quando utilizados como canais de dados) são o modelo.

Fica a cargo do desenvolvedor *backend* implementar persistência (C/VM). O modelo de desenvolvimento e localização funcional dependerá necessariamente da distribuição de responsabilidades, e isso tem mais a ver com o modelo de processo do que a escolha de plataforma em si.

> *[...] tem como utilizar um desses frameworks somente a parte da "view"?*"

**Sim**. Aliás, esta seria a única maneira.

(A sua pergunta é um pouco ampla demais. Talvez fosse interessante você definir algumas dúvidas específicas que lhe ajudem a visualizar o modelo.)

Comment: Acabei sendo muito abrangente por estar confuso. Tinha uma concepção sobre MVC que separava as camadas, e que por acaso um desses frameworks entrarariam somente na view e o resto seguiria normalmente, mas ao ver o angular.JS bugou tudo, criando a ideia de ter MVC do lado do cliente(tudo voltado para ele, ate os dados) ou que existe MVC do lado do cliente e do lado do servidor. Eu Nao sou desenvolvedor front, Nao quero me aprofundar muito, continuando meu foco no back, mas quero incluir a performance e interfaces SPA de forma Nao muito "drástica", foi onde eu vi o Vue.JS, mas contínuo confuso.

Comment: @Marcial pense da seguinte maneira - MV* descreve uma maneira como processos são gerenciados dentro de um escopo da solução. Uma aplicação pode ter vários segmentos (e várias camadas MV*.) A parte M* de uma aplicação Angular (seus serviços de dados) é completamente independente da M* da solução completa (por exemplo as interfaces ORM doi backend).

Comment: Entendi, fiz algumas outras pesquisas, e vi que pode se ter o MVC tanto no lado do Client e no Servidor, a diferença é que o MVC no lado do cliente tratara da interface e manipulação dos dados com as especificações da forma mvc, como se fosse duas aplicações, Aplicação de interface e a do servidor, cada uma desempenhando seu papel. O que me deixou confuso foi achar que toda responsabilidade seria passada para o cliente, ate mesmo as regras de negocio, na verdade seria o tratamento do dados para serem enviados ao servidor. E quando dizem que o Vue.js é apenas "View", esta correto? @OnoSendai

Comment: @Marcial Exatamente isso. Cada camada (frontend, backend) pode ter sua própria implementação MV*.

Comment: Complementando: Sendo uma aplicação MVC(hibrida), com um framework front na "View" e o Back com o "Model", porem os dois lados podem ser MVC internamente, tanto no back e no front. Ter a visão de que uma certa tecnologia(MVC por exemplo) se encaixa somente em um contexto me fez ter essa confusão anterior, acredito que estou indo ao caminho correto agora. O controler seria independente dos dois? No caso de uma aplicação SPA, seria o "Ajax"? Fazendo a comunicação dos dois lados. @OnoSendai

Comment: @Marcial Exato. Muito da confusão ainda vem de práticas de desenvolvimento nativo (aplicações Windows, por exemplo) onde a camada única - e consequentemente o modelo mais simples - faz a visualização das responsabilidades ser mais fácil. Em uma aplicação SPA, o controller seria a parte responsável pela coordenação entre dados (services e factories) e a interface (partials e views.)

Comment: No caso são eles que faram a ponte entre os lados, sendo assim o ajax por trás? Isso esta abrindo bastante minha mente, obrigado @OneSendai